# Playing WAV file in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

We are trying to play a wav file located in /sound through the audio tag. This works inside of the browser (phonegap serve) but it doesn't work when we run it on Android.

We get the error 'Failed to open file (no such file or directory)'. Why does this happen (while it works on the browser) and how can we fix this?

Here is our code:

HTML

```
<audio id="effects" src="./sound/hit.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

JavaScript

```
var effectPlayer = document.getElementById('effects');
effectPlayer.play();
```